# Need help in writing proper search query via PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

Right now I am trying to make a Java console app with the purpose of easier filling my database (I've just started to learn Java, so excuse me for bad using of term).

I am using Hibernate and JDBC for it. So I got several classes, two of them are Country and City. First of all, I will fill Country, next I will fill City, because I linked them with one to many (Country->City).

I need to write a method which will accept the String `countryname` from Scanner,  search it in the Country table and then return the id of this country. I need help with writing a MySQL query.

```
public static countrySearch(String countryname){

    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/freeguide", "root", "6235");
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select id from Country where countryname LIKE (?) ");
        //Here is where I am stuck

    }    

    catch (SQLException e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return countryid;

}
```

Comment: You are using the 'raw' database connection, rather than a Hibernate Session. Therefore, your prepared statement expects raw SQL rather than HQL. Your code doesn't actually include any Hibernate references, and nor will your database.

Comment: I have removed the hibernate tag, the code shown does not involve hibernate. And your question looks like it would be answered by any decent tutorial on JDBC, so please elaborate om what you're stuck on.